# Ansible Tower - aws_s3 module - set python interpreter and install dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-awx

I am trying to deploy the below task via Ansible AWX (Tower) and having some issues with the aws_s3 module.

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Setting host facts for Python interpreter
      set_fact: 
        ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"
   
    - name: 01 - Download file locally
      aws_s3:
        bucket: temp-buck-0001
        object: /test/quiz.sh
        dest: /tmp/quiz.sh
        mode: get

    - name: 02 - Change the file permissions of the shell scrip to allow for execute
      file: 
        path: /tmp/quiz.sh
        mode: "u=x"

    - name: 03 - Change the working directory to tmp before executing the command.
      shell: quiz.sh >> quizlog.txt
      args:
        chdir: /tmp
```

I'm getting the below error when trying to deploy the above ansible play. It seems to have a problem with Python dependencies in particular boto3 and botocore so I attempted to install these manually for testing purposes.

However, I'm receiving the below errors. It concerns dependencies for the aws_s3 module. I'm not sure if I have set up my Python interpreter correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, if anybody could suggest how to write a task to install Python3x and dependencies which is required for the aws_s3 module that would also be much appreciated.

> TASK [01 - Download Metricbeats file locally]
> ********************************** fatal: [Dev-02]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 20.10.12.114
> closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python3: No such
> file or directory\r\n", "msg": "The module failed to execute
> correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee
> stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}

and the below output

> {   "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or
> directory\r\n",   "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 20.10.12.114
> closed.\r\n",   "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you
> probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact
> error",   "rc": 127,   "_ansible_no_log": false,   "changed": false }

For context, this is the version of Python I have installed:

```
[ec2-user@ip-20-10-12-114 ~]$ pip --version   
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
[ec2-user@ip-20-10-12-114 ~]$ which pip   
/usr/bin/pip      
[ec2-user@ip-20-10-12-114 ~]$ python --version   
Python 2.7.18
[ec2-user@ip-20-10-12-114 ~]$ which python   
/usr/bin/python     
[ec2-user@ip-20-10-12-114 ~]$ python3 --version   
Python 3.6.2
[ec2-user@ip-20-10-12-114 ~]$ which python3   
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: You have to understand why you think there is a `/usr/bin/python3` binary on your target host while ansible cannot find it. Please not that from what I can read, the machine on which your are manually verifying (20.10.12.114) seems different from the one ansible is trying to connect to (20.10.11.14). Regarding python deps needed on the target, you typically fix that with a (abbridged to single yaml line...) `- pip: { name: [package1, package2] }` before you launch a dependant task.

Comment: sorry, the IP address confusion is because I had two lots of output from two different servers. To avoid confusion, I have pasted the output from the correct server.

Comment: from your reply above, should i then install python packages via ansible excluding the interpreter statement and then give it a try?

Comment: You should always be aware of what python interpreter you use, either because of auto-discovery or because you set it (and in this later case the interpreted should exist which is obviously not what ansible thinks from your error message). And then you should install the required py modules with pip, ansible bein the most straightforward way in your particular case I guess.